# Not able to resolve org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using selenium RC to run our test cases, but while running it is throwing error as
below

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver

Please help me as I am stuck with this problem from past 1 week

Answer (score 0):

Check you downloaded the selenium server with dependencies included, and check whether  org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver is in your classpath